# Bind an Ember checkbox to the opposite value of a property

Tags: ember.js

I have a model `foo` with the property `bar`. When I render an ember checkbox, I want to bind the `checked` property to `foo.bar` such that when the box is checked `foo.bar` is `false` and when unchecked, `foo.bar` is `true`

Doing:

```
{{input
  type='checkbox'
  checked=foo.bar}}
```

gets me the opposite of what I want, while

```
{{input
  type='checkbox'
  checked=(not foo.bar)}}
```

does not bind the value of `foo.bar` to the `checked` property. How can I solve this without adding a new `notBar` property to `foo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
<input
 type='checkbox'
 onchange={{action (toggle 'bar' foo)}}
 checked={{not foo.bar}}>
```

Using https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers#toggle

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
<input
 type='checkbox'
 onchange={{action (mut foo.bar) (not foo.bar)}}
 checked={{not foo.bar}}>
```

You dont need an external toggle helper for this.